# Unable to start a new vite project -

Tags: vite, yarnpkg

Wen I run:

```
yarn create vite@latest project -- --template react-ts
```

It fails with:

```
yarn create v1.22.17
warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "create-vite@4.3.2" with binaries:
      - create-vite
      - cva
/bin/sh: 1: /home/user/.yarn/bin/create-vite@latest: not found
error Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: /home/user/.yarn/bin/create-vite@latest
Arguments: project --template react-ts
Directory: /home/user/Work
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. I'm running exactly what the vite website recommends on it's getting started guide.

What am I missing?

Comment: the same here, npm works fine though

Comment: What is the output of: `node --version` ?   (Because I have 12.22.9, I am getting: `create-vite@4.3.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^14.18.0 || >=16.0.0". Got "12.22.9"`)

Comment: upgrade to yarn 2?